# Committing Code in Git where branch is ahead of origin by one commit

Tags: git, version-control

I have a scenario where i am working on a qa environment. I made some changes into the source code using vi editor. Now i want to commit above changes into the branch and then possibly push the branch to origin. But at first i want to commit my changes.

Here is what git status shows for me:

[image: Git Screenshot]
Now what i read about is using git -m "Msg"   .. i can commit my changes. But i am not sure about that and other thing is i am seeing the message **Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit** So i a not sure how to proceed further. I am quiet new to Git and don't want to break things. In case you want me to write any command and paste the output please let me know.

Comment: The fact that you are one commit ahead of your remote is normal.  You will not be ahead of it, once you push those commits (In this case, one commit) to the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Three Stage Thinking

In `git`, you work with your source in three stages:

**Edit** - **Add** - **Commit**

First, you **edit** your files. As you make changes to files, the output of `git status` will change to reflect the modifications you've made. You can view the changes you've made so far with `git diff`.

Next, you **add**, or stage, your work. Stage all of the changes to a particular file with `git add <file>`. Again, the output of `git status` will change to reflect what you've staged. You can view the changes you have staged with `git diff --cached`.

Last, you **commit** your changes. When you run `git commit`, whatever files you have staged will be bundled up into a commit. A commit includes a snapshot of your repository, a commit message, time, and author. You can view your commits with `git log`. `git log -p` in particular will show the changes made in each commit.

## Pushing

Before you try pushing any code, I recommend talking to your co-workers about what the contribution guidelines are for this repository. For example, they may want you to push to a certain branch or go through a code review process.

Answer (score 2):

This is Git 101, CodeMonkey, the stuff you'll learn on your first day of Git class, but I'll bite.

It tells you on that screen what to do - use `git add <file>` to add each file, e.g. `git add docs/smarty/templates/google.tpl` to add it. As a shortcut, if you want to add all of those modified files, use `git add --update .` (note the dot). If you do another `git status` at that point, it'll tell you how to proceed from there to make your commit, which will be `git commit -m'Your commit message'`.

You're one commit ahead of origin, because you've either made a commit, or the branch on origin that you're tracking has been moved back to the commit before where you are now. Once you've committed these files, you can `git push origin 1693-m` to sync the origin remote's branch up with your branch. If new commits have come in to origin since the last time you fetched or pulled from there, you'll have to rebase your new commits on top of those, likely with a `git pull --rebase`, then do the `git push`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i have never taken a Git class. Reading http://gitref.org/branching/#branch to get a grasp of things. I am sure once i try Git a few times i would be good at it. 


So according to you i shall do git add first then git commit ? i thought git add is for all files which i have created new.

Comment: Git is unusual in the world of versioning in that you not only add and commit new files, but also modified files. You'll learn about that when you learn about the index, AKA the staging area, which is where you're actually adding both of these kinds of changes before committing them.

Comment: Gary Can you suggest some good links for tutorials. I may really wana go dive into Git. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I really like [The Git Parable](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html). It walks you through how you might discover and create git yourself with some time, motivation, and creativity. It won't teach you how to use git, but you'll gain a better understanding of why it works the way it does. The [Git Pro Book](http://git-scm.com/book) is one of the best tech/ref books I've read, and many of the chapters are pretty quick, easy reads.

Answer (score 1):

When you `git pull` or `git push` a remote your branch will be in sync with the remote branch.  After that, every time you commit something you get out of sync by one unit.  So the '**Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit**' means that you have committed one time after your last push/pull.

This is all normal.  You'll do many commits locally, happily improving your code, and then, when you are ready, you'll `git pull` and then `git push` to the remote.  You do a `pull` to get other changes people on your team might have made.  After the `pull`, if there are changes, you'll re-check your code, fix any problems, and then `push`.